# Excessive syslog messages

Tags: syslog, cgroups

I am getting a huge amount of log messages in `/var/log/syslog` all of the sudden (5GB/day).  I think it has to do with my recent adoption of cgroups but I'm not sure.

Here is what I see:

```
Jun 29 06:25:01 ip-10-0-0-244 CGRE[7308]: EXEC Event: PID = 19729, tGID = 19729
Jun 29 06:25:01 ip-10-0-0-244 CGRE[1679]: EXEC Event: PID = 19732, tGID = 19732
```

Assuming it is cgroups, I know of the CGROUP_LOGLEVEL environmental variable.  But where do I set this so it would survive reboots? /etc/environment?

This also looks promising but I can't find anyone discussing the use of these tools: https://linux.die.net/man/8/cgrulesengd

EDIT: I tried doing `sudo /usr/sbin/cgrulesengd --quiet --quiet` but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had dozens of `cgrulesengd` processes running.  I think they were all sending messages to syslog.

I ended up with all those processes because I was using this command to "refresh" after I changed cgroup rules: `sudo /usr/sbin/cgrulesengd`. I did not realize that each time I call it that it spawned a new instance.

I will edit my answer if I can figure out the proper way to reload the daemon when rules change.